# Checkout Button Callbacks don't work if customer is using 2 factor authentication

Tags: coinbase-api

Checkout Button Callbacks don't work if customer is using 2 factor authentication.

I mean, customer can pay with checkout button but if they are using 2fa, they can pay with coinbase but callbacks doesn't work.

My code is below.

```
<a class="buy-with-crypto m-option" href="https://commerce.coinbase.com/checkout/<?php echo $key; ?>">
     <span><img src="/theme-assets/images/coinbase250px.png" class="img-fluid" style=""></span>
</a>
<script src="https://commerce.coinbase.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    BuyWithCrypto.registerCallback('onSuccess', function(e){
       window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>subscription/coinbase_payment_result/"+e.code+"/<?php echo $order['id']; ?>"; });

    BuyWithCrypto.registerCallback('onFailure', function(e){
       alert('Your charge has been failed.'); });
</script>
```

Thanks